# setuptools entry_point: point to an executable module/package?

Tags: python, setuptools

In a `setup.py` file, is it possible to point `entry_points` (which creates stuff in `.../bin`) to an executable module or package? That is, if I have the following setup:

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  __main__.py
```

I can do `python3 -m foo`, and Python will execute the package. (This is convienent as it lets relative imports work.)

In a `setup.py` script, I can add binaries to `.../bin` w/ something like,

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ['foo=foo.bar:func'],
},
```

which executes the *function* `foo.bar.func()` (assuming it exists); is it possible to have it do something akin to `python3 -m foo`? Or is it hard-wired to only do functions?

(I can, of course, move all my code into a function called `main()`¹, and `foo.__main__:main` seems to work. It just feels like this aspect of `setuptools` and the `-m` aspect of Python 3 really should work together, but AFAICT, really don't? Is this just an example of separate things not meshing well?)

<sub>¹Which I do normally anyways, as it feels like it's good practice.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To execute the quivalent to `-m` from Python code explicitly, have a look at [`runpy.run_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html?highlight=run_module#runpy.run_module). You make a script with that code and put it into [`scripts`](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html?highlight=entry_points#the-scripts-keyword-argument).

Alternatively (and perhaps, preferrably), you place the "startup code" that fires on `-m` to a function, then register that function as an entry point:

```
def main():
    <...>

if __name__ == '__main__.py':
    main()
```

Comment: The point of putting it in `entry_points` to s.t. it's a proper binary on the `PATH`; I don't want the user to have to know `python3 -m <module>` as a magic incantation.

Comment: Is it better now?